# Latex Bibliography Not printing as expected

Tags: article

Search, and research

I've figured out how to code the bibliography. I've created a section titled `bibliography.tex`. My goal is to show the 7 references from my `literature.bib` file in the `bibliography.tex` file.

Be on-topic
The goal of this question is to understand why the citations are not showing up in the `bibliography.tex` file.

[image]

Be specific
The citation associated with **Surveying a suite of algorithms that offer a solution to managing large document archives**
shows up just fine. I would like to know why one of the `@article` citations shows up, but the other `@article` citations do not show up. For example, `Exploring the Space of Topic Coherence Measures` does not show up.

```
@article{chang2009,
  title= "Reading Tea Leaves: How Humans Interpret Topic Models",
  author="Jonathan Chang, Jordan Boyd-Graber and Sean Gerrish, Chong Wang, David M. Blei",
  journal="ACM",
  year="2009"
}

@article{röder2010,
  title="Exploring the Space of Topic Coherence Measures",
  author="Michael Röder, Andreas Both, Alexander Hinneburg",
  journal="ACM",
  year="2015"
}

@article{blei2012,
  title="Surveying a suite of algorithms that offer a solution to managing large document archives.",
  author="David M. BLEI, Probabilistic Topic Models",
  journal="ACM",
  year="2012"
}

@article{praveen2021,
  title="Surveying a suite of algorithms that offer a solution to managing large document archives.",
  author="Praveen Suthaharan, Erin J. Reed, Pantelis Leptourgos, Joshua G. Kenney, Stefan Uddenberg, Christoph D. Mathys, Leib Litman, Jonathan Robinson, Aaron J. Moss, Jane R. Taylor, Stephanie M. Groman, Philip R. Corlett",
  journal="Nature",
  year="2021"
}

@BOOK{datamining,
  TITLE = {Data Mining},
  SUBTITLE = {Concepts and Techniques},
  AUTHOR = {Jiawei Han, Micheline Kamber, Jian Pei},
  PUBLISHER = {Morgan Kaufman},
}

@misc{redditDataSet,
  author = {umbrae},
  title = {Reddit Top 2.5 Million},
  year = {2017},
  publisher = {GitHub},
  journal = {GitHub repository},
  howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/hanzohan/reddit-top-2.5-million.git}},
}

@misc{englishWord,
  author = {deekayen},
  title = {1-1000.txt},
  year = {2021},
  publisher = {GitHub},
  journal = {GitHub repository},
  howpublished = {\url{https://gist.github.com/deekayen/4148741}},
}
```

Make it relevant to others
This question will help others avoid repeating the same mistake when creating a bibliography in Latex. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you citing all the entries?

Comment: While you may have tried to elaborate on each element of a good question, this doesn't make sense. What you show in the image is a single `@article` citation, not "other `@article` citations." The others are `@misc`, or `@book`. Can you please update your question, and be specific in terms of what you ask? Questions like "I'm trying to figure out the difference..." seems vague.

Comment: @Werner I've updated the question.

Comment: Try adding `\nocite{*}` to your preamble; depending on what citation package you're using, they may only be included if they're used.

Comment: That works. Thanks!